# Почему prototype пустой и одновременно со свойствами

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript

Вот простой код для node:

```
class Samurai {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  hello() { console.log(this.name) }
}

let shogun = new Samurai("Dimych")

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Samurai.prototype))
console.log(Samurai.prototype)
```

Его результат:

```
[ 'constructor', 'hello' ]
{}
```

То есть у этого объекта есть собственные методы contructor и hello, но во втором выводе пустой объект, почему так происходит? При этом браузер выводит непустой объект в котором эти свойства перечислены

Comment: `console.log()` не стандартизирован. Видимо по этому такой вывод - не выводит стандартные унаследованные методы и свойства. Однакое если унаследоваться от другого класса то увидим в качестве прототима класс родитель или добавить новый метод, например так `Samurai.prototype.bye = function () { console.log(`bye ${this.name}`); }` то в прототипе появляется новый метод

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А где можно смотреть что стандартизированно, а что нет? Можно ссылку на сайт?

Comment: Проще [почитать тут](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.63fa819d-64d5516c-27d0a187-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/52070294/javascript-why-isnt-console-considered-a-standard-built-in-object). Спецификации можно взять [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/manuals-specifications)